# How to I get started with Apache Thrift?

Tags: thrift, thrift-protocol

I wanted to create a simple Thrift server for C++ and provide a client with Python language. I went to the official site but it lacks any good tutorials or documentation. I am having difficulty trying it out.

Is there any good Apache Thrift tutorial for a totally new person?

Answer (score 21):

[Thrift: The Missing Guide](http://diwakergupta.github.com/thrift-missing-guide/) is very useful to begin with.

Comment: My blog post on trying thrift in Python (Chinese version): http://sunliwen.com/2012/02/apache-thrift-on-ubuntu-10-04/  (English)http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsunliwen.com%2F2012%2F02%2Fapache-thrift-on-ubuntu-10-04%2F

Answer (score 10):

I have put together a 7-part tutorial for Thrift in my blog. The link to the first part of the article is below:

http://anoori.me/blog/programming/thriftpart-one-introduction

Comment: this link is not working

Comment: @sonic Sorry, there is an issue with the domain. The site will definitely be up soon. I'll try to remember to comment here when it does (if I remember :D)

Comment: @sonic Updated the link. Sorry it took so long. I have to change the links manually since I've lost my domain.

Answer (score 3):

The archive of standard distribution contains the Calculator tutorial pointed by @vladaman.
The documentation isn't quite well organized, but there are plenty of info at http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/. Take a look at "Thrift Whitepaper" and "Thrift: The Missing Guide".

Answer (score 2):

Another useful overview of Thrift can be found at http://jnb.ociweb.com/jnb/jnbJun2009.html

Comment: This is the only one that describes the protocols, transports and servers and which one is right for your project.